# jquery check which li is display block and get value

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get value of a product from a list of li of same ul which in display:block (others are hidden). how ever when i click on to choose a different product size the price changes and the li display:block changes to none whith that li having the price related to cliked size being display:block now . I want to get the value from the li which is display:block but its saying undefined . can anyone help me out with this my code is

```
 $(document).on("click", ".sizes li", function() {
 if ($('.sizes-list li').is(':visible'))
 {
 var price=$(this).find('dd').html();
 alert(price);
 }
 });
```

markup for li for sizes-list ul

```
<ul class="sizes-list">
<li style="display:block"><dd>$7</dd></li>
<li><dd>$8</dd></li>
<li><dd>$9</dd></li>
</ul>
```

markup for li for size ul (on size buttons)

```
<ul class="sizes">
<li><a href="#">Small</dd></a>
<li><a href="#">Medium</dd></a>
<li><a href="#">Large</dd></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjryT/4/

which has the updated script here:

```
jQuery("ul.sizes-list li").each(function () {

  if (jQuery(this).css("display") == "block")
  {
    jQuery(this).on("click", function () 
    {
        var price = jQuery(this).find("dd:first").text();
      alert(price);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: please can you check the markup i have two different ul from one which i click to get price from display block of other